# how to increase ejb thread size in Jboss 6

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss

I have a long-time running application that runs behind Jboss Application server 6.I have some performance problems in these days.When 12 cores running in client side, after some time system starts to be slower.think that Jboss is not able to handle all requests from client with default configuration. There are some communication problems by connecting and disconnecting from server. So My aim is to make performance tuning at Jboss side.

I have read following statements regarding to thread pooling.

The system thread pool defined in jboss-service.xml in the conf directory 
is for JNDI naming.

● This rarely needs to be updated from the default.

I checked my jboss-service.xml.There is no place to define thread count in the file.can you plase help how can I change thread/Pool  size for performance tuning.

There are 12 minutes idle time in the client.Client waits for the server.From time to time finalizer thread is trying to disconnect  in the meantime.

```
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[119b3ab4,   socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[1fe2251e, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[1fe2251e, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[377a5053, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[377a5053, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[758be9ad, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[758be9ad, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[45e4da31, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[45e4da31, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[72f99d14, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[72f99d14, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[421b20de, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[421b20de, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[3d59d675, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[3d59d675, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[43c4d971,  socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[43c4d971, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[39a01920, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[39a01920, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[11f2440a, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[11f2440a,  socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[77535378, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[77535378, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[791f45d2, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[791f45d2,    socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[4c54c6f9, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[4c54c6f9, socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...
```

12:31:20,327 [      Finalizer] DEBUG SocketClientInvoker[20260913,        socket://127.0.0.1:3873] disconnecting ...

Comment: have you measured where the bottleneck is? what are "some communication problems"? how is your client connecting to your app?

Comment: It uses ejb methods to retrieve/insert data

Answer (score 0):

This thread seems to indicate that under the hood JBoss AS 6 uses Tomcat 6 : https://community.jboss.org/message/596832

In tomcat 6, you set the maxThreads in the thread pool using the Executor element : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html

A sample Executor element is shown here : http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/admin/radmserverbasic.html